# Generac GP8000e/Need to be grounded? Remove Neutral?

Tags: electrical-panel, generator, neutral, grounding-and-bonding

I have a Generac GP8000e generator that I plan on back feeding the main panel of my home with the portable generator, power inlet box L14-30a and breaker. First, I will install an interlock between the utility main breaker and the generator back feed breaker. I will only use the L14-30 receptacle to power my home.

1. Do I need to ground my generator with 8’ rods etc.?
2. Do I need to remove the neutral ground from my generator since my main panel already has that?

Comment: I take it you plan to dedicate this generator to standby power duty, right?

Comment: "portable generator, power inlet box L14-30a and breaker" You should add an interlock kit on that breaker, to keep from accidentally backfeeding the power lines and hurting line workers.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to ground my generator with 8' rods etc.?

No. That is normally required at the main panel (defined by ground/neutral bond) and at any subpanels in additional buildings. The grounding system serves two functions:

- Path from branch circuits back to panel to enable trip of breakers in certain situations (e.g., hot to ground short). The generator is more like a branch circuit (except it is providing power, not consuming power) in this respect - it is not functioning as a panel. In fact, it is possible (depending on the size of the generator vs. the size of the breaker in the main panel) that the generator could have an overcurrent situation where the generator's internal breaker will *not* trip but the breaker in the main panel *will* trip for safety.
- Path for excess natural electricity to go back to the ground, such as lightning. This could come from any branch and go back to the main panel. A detached building needs its own ground rods as that provides a shorter (= faster, less potential for damage) path for localized problems, but a generator again acts as a branch circuit in this respect.

> Do I need to remove the neutral ground from my generator since my main panel already has that?

Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe silly to weigh in after 4 months, but have new researching this and talking with electricians I work with. The standard practice for back feeding a genset is the usual physical interlock, and using a floating neutral generator.

If your generator has the neutral bonded (if it has standard 110 outlets, it does), then I'm not saying you can't make it floating. And I'm also not saying you can't very clearly label it as a floating neutral generator unfit for direct use, and not saying you should not disable the 110 outlets for liability.